# How do I get the tables referenced within a table-valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need something like this but instead of outputting stored procedures and the tables they referenced, SQL Server table-valued function and the tables they referenced. Thanks all.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    [DB Name] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Stored Procedure] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Schema] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Table] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT DISTINCT ''?'',
 sp.Name [Stored Procedure],
    ''['' + spsch.name + '']'' [Schema],
    ''['' + o.Name + '']'' [Table]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies sd WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.object_id = sd.referenced_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects sp WITH (NOLOCK) ON sd.referencing_id = sp.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas spsch WITH (NOLOCK) ON sp.schema_id = spsch.schema_id
    AND sp.type IN (''P'')
ORDER BY [Stored Procedure],
    [Table]
'

SELECT *
FROM #temp a
ORDER BY [DB NAME],
    [STORED PROCEDURE],
    [TABLE]
```

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: @SMor `nolock` is pretty standard with DMV (system tables) queries to prevent nasty locking chains across the whole DB, probably the only time you should use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is super easy. Just Turn the P in your IN Clause to FN. See below:

[image]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    [DB Name] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Stored Procedure] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Schema] VARCHAR(MAX),
    [Table] VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]; INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT DISTINCT ''?'',
 sp.Name [Stored Procedure],
    ''['' + spsch.name + '']'' [Schema],
    ''['' + o.Name + '']'' [Table]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies sd WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.object_id = sd.referenced_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects sp WITH (NOLOCK) ON sd.referencing_id = sp.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas spsch WITH (NOLOCK) ON sp.schema_id = spsch.schema_id
    AND sp.type IN (''FN'')
ORDER BY [Stored Procedure],
    [Table]
'

SELECT *
FROM #temp a
ORDER BY [DB NAME],
    [STORED PROCEDURE],
    [TABLE]
```